# How to convert Coorinates of VectorFeatures or Layer in OpenLayers from one projection to another?

Tags: gwt, openlayers, gwt-openlayers

I'm using GWT-OpenLayers in my project and i have problems with converting coordinates.
I know how to do this for single point `transform(from,to)` but can i do this without applyinng for each point?
Right now i'm parsing KLM data to get list of features and i'm adding them to new vector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `transform` on any Geometry, it should just work. Multi-point geometries inherit from `OpenLayers.Geometry.Collection` which has its own [`transform`](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Collection-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Collection.transform) method.